# how to update a Document within an Array that belongs to a outer document?

Tags: meteor, minimongo

I have the following Document:

```
mainDoc = {
        owner: Meteor.userId(),
        createdOn: new Date(),
        active: false,
        label: "Dashboard #" + ($("ul#u-nav-tabs").find("li.u-tab").length + 1),
        monitors: [/*Embedded documents*/],
        sharewith: []
    };
```

`mainDoc.monitors` is an array of the following documents:

```
innerDoc = {
                _id: id._str,
                owner: Meteor.userId(),
                createdOn: new Date(),
                label: monitorLabel,
                metadata: {custDate: {}},
                style: {
                    top: mystyle.top,
                    left: mystyle.left,
                    width: 0,
                    height: 0
                },
                shown: true,
                sharewith: []
            }
```

I have set the following permissions on the server

```
userDashboards.allow({
    insert: function (userId) {
        "use strict";
        return userId;
    },
    update: function (userId, doc) {
        "use strict";
        return doc.owner === userId;
    },
    remove: function (userId, doc) {
        "use strict";
        return doc.owner === userId;
    },
    fetch: ["owner", "monitors"]
});
```

I tried this so far on the client:

```
console.log(userDashboards.findOne({"monitors._id": "5f94f2a15bddd908f2bc9d5d"}));
```

But I only get the full document, not the embedded document.

So the question is, how can I update `innerDoc.style` directly and from the browser?

Comment: hey @Ethaan ! I kind of still the problem, I found a partial solution in [here][1] but now I have a problem how I allow that collection to be updated :-( I get this error:
Uncaught Error: Not permitted. Untrusted code may only update documents by ID. \[403\]


    [1]: http://maz-dev.cc/update-on-mongo-subdocuments/

Comment: it helped me, I had ANOTHER problem and I solved it with your solution

Answer (score 0):

Try with this.

**Updating**

```
userDashboards.update({_id:"5f94f2a15bddd908f2bc9d5d"},{$set:{'monitors[0]._id':"yeaaa look mom im editing documents with arrays"}})
```

Assuming "5f94f2a15bddd908f2bc9d5d" its `._id` not `monitors._id.`
Like you say monitors is an array, so you should specify the index aka [0].
Remember the syntaxis of the update should be like this.

```
    Collection.update({_id:idDocument},{$set:{fieldToUpdate:newData}}) // correct

Collection.update({_id:idDocument,$set:{fieldToUpdate:newData}}) // wrong, you will get some "stack error" 

Collection.update({$set:{fieldToUpdate:newData}}) // wrong, you need to specify what document will be update and by stric the id should be always {_id:"5f94f2a15bddd908f2bc9d5d"} <-- like this
```

That should works.

Comment: @juanp_1982, i make and update to the answer, just to make it more clear